# using count equivalent in mongodb to find top users with max occurence

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have my mongoDB data in the format

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5284a1ac5fac01f0099cc6a8"), "date" : ISODate("2013-11-15T12:40:53Z"), "data_id" : "data_1", "application_id" : "myapplication", "user" : "user_1"}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5284a1ac5fac01f0099cc6a8"), "date" : ISODate("2013-11-16T12:40:53Z"), "data_id" : "data_2", "application_id" : "myapplication", "user" : "user_2"}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5284a1ac5fac01f0099cc6a8"), "date" : ISODate("2013-11-16T12:40:53Z"), "data_id" : "data_3", "application_id" : "myapplication", "user" : "user_1"}
```

I want to find the top 10 users which have maximum entries in the mongoDB. How do I use aggregate's `$group`, `$sort` and `count` command to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

1. You have to grup users & count the occurrence of entries
2. Using **$sort** parameter you can sort by the number of entries in decreasing order
3. By using **$limit** you can retrieve the first 10 users.

   ```
   db.myCollection.aggregate(
       {$group : {_id : "$user", "count" : {$sum : 1}}},
       {$sort : {"count" : -1}},
       {$limit : 10}
   )
   ```

Comment: are you sure `{$sort : {count : -1}}` this part will work. Rest works like a champ

Comment: that all works.
I was very close to answer, you caught it fast :).
Accepting your answer

Comment: and to apply something like where clause as in SQL, we can use `$match` in aggregation `$match:{application_id:"myapplication"}`
I never knew mongodb is such a powerful database option